# EF 5.0 Code First Stand Alone Table

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I'm using EF 5.0 Code First to develop an app with a number of relational db tables.  This works great until I try to add a table without any relationship (stand alone).  I need a number of these reference/lookup tables in my db.  I code my classes just like the others but EF seems to ignore them and doesn't create them.  Is there something I need to tell EF that these should be built as stand alone?  How?  Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How did you tell EF about those tables? Have you added mapping for them or created DbSet property for those entities in your context?

Comment: There is no mapping for them but I still needed to create the DbSet property which I did not do.  This fixed it.  If you reply as answer I will select your response.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get EF to create a table you need a `DbSet<T>` in your `DbContext`, assuming you have this it will create the table.

The one caviat to this is that if you have a foreign key to something that isn't in you context EF will also assume its part of the database and create it. I think this is the behavior you are seeing.

Comment: I did not add the DbSet<T> in the context which was the problem.  It now creates the tables.  Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

EF should does not have any restrictions for "standalone" tables.

When you build EF tables once, additional changes will have to be followed by

- update of Context class (subclass of `DbContext`)
- adding migration script (generates API calls which will update database with new tables etc.)
- update database (run migration script).

You can find really good tutorial [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj193542).

Comment: Can you please clarify "should not" or "does not" and point to where I can verify this?  Also, I am using DropCreateDatabaseAlways as my initializer during development so don't need migrations yet.

Comment: In my opinion EF **does not** have any restrictions for "standalone" tables. I have been using EF 5 in several projects (with "standalone" tables) and never had any issues as you (especially when you use `DropCreateDatabaseAlways` DB initialization). However, I used **should not** as maybe you came across a bug. Maybe adding a bit more code to the description would give us some clues.

Comment: You are correct.  I failed to enter the DbSet<T> in the context as Luke pointed out above.  Thanks for your help.